# Custom Search Results Page

Tags: customization, search

I am trying to create a custom search results page. I am not allowed to edit the php files directly. I have been using [include_php] short codes to write as little php code as possible.

I am trying to keep users away from the default 'posts' page, therefore when a user searches, I want a custom page that links users to a page that I have built myself, not its corresponding post page.

Is there any way I can do this without editing php files?

Comment: Thank you for your question, but you might have better luck asking on the WordPress support forums. This site is geared towards development ()which you've said you can't use in this case) and third-party plugins are out of scope here.

Comment: you should not insert php into the content with those shortcodes. This is both insecure and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly override the page you want them not to see. 
So for example, if you have a portfolio page that looks one way, you can override that by having a custom portfolio.php of your own.

In there you can modify the look, but also you can setup your custom query that will basically override the search to show what you want to show.

There is not really anyway to do it without editing any PHP files, but to avoid losing changes I would suggest putting your new templates in a child theme or plugin.

This might help you with the templates available and how they are used.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/